# need right steps and good practice with encryption a string in creating android application

Tags: android, encryption

i am creating android application that will allow the user to a string as a plain text and a password to encrypt this string and then the system will display the encrypted string or the cypherText.
 but the problem is that the system do not show anything  can anyone help me ??
where is the error in my code and how to make this application to work .

## log cat

```
01-04 16:13:40.362: W/EGL_genymotion(2247): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-04 16:13:40.402: D/dalvikvm(2247): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 162K, 2% free 16888K/17072K, paused 13ms, total 19ms
01-04 16:13:51.082: W/System.err(2247): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 16:13:51.082: W/System.err(2247):     at com.devleb.testforencdemo.MainActivity.Encrypt(MainActivity.java:79)
01-04 16:13:51.082: W/System.err(2247):     at com.devleb.testforencdemo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)
01-04 16:13:51.082: W/System.err(2247):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-04 16:13:51.082: W/System.err(2247):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-04 16:13:51.082: W/System.err(2247):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-04 16:13:51.082: W/System.err(2247):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-04 16:13:51.082: W/System.err(2247):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 16:13:51.090: W/System.err(2247):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-04 16:13:51.094: W/System.err(2247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 16:13:51.098: W/System.err(2247):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-04 16:13:51.102: W/System.err(2247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-04 16:13:51.102: W/System.err(2247):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-04 16:13:51.102: W/System.err(2247):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.testforencdemo;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String plaintTxt1;
    String pass1;

    String plaintxt;
    String strPass;
    String cypherTxt = "";
    EditText strTxt;
    EditText editStrPass;

    TextView encryptTxt;

    Button btn;

    int iterations = 200;
    byte[] salt = { (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC6, (byte) 0xFE,
            (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x77 };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        strTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxtSTR);
        plaintxt = strTxt.getText().toString();

        encryptTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.encryptSTR);
        editStrPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxtPass);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Encrypt(plaintTxt1, pass1, salt);
            }
        });

    }

    public static String toBase64(byte[] bytes) {
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    public void Encrypt(String pltxt, String pass, byte[] salte) {
        strPass = editStrPass.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, strPass, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(pass.toCharArray());
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
                    .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            SecretKey pbeKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
            Log.e("SecreteKey", pbeKey.toString());
            PBEParameterSpec pbeSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salte, iterations);
            Log.e("SecreteKey", pbeSpec.toString());
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pbeKey, pbeSpec);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(pltxt.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            cypherTxt = String.format("%s%s%s", toBase64(salt), "]",
                    toBase64(cipherText));
            encryptTxt.setText(cypherTxt);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`pass` not initialize before this line

```
 PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(pass.toCharArray());
```